# R function bquote() does not have the same number of elements as expression()

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of characters like this

```
vec <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

And I want to change the first element of the vector with an expression

```
num <- 3
vec[1] <- expression(num^4)
```

However, if I try to use `x[1]` for a label in a plot

```
plot(x=1, xlab = vec[1])
```

I get the following label:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBERN.jpg)

Is there any way that the label can read 3<sup>4</sup>? I did some research and saw that some people suggested using the `bquote()` function. But when I try this

```
num <- 3
vec[1] <- bquote(.(num)^4)
```

I get the error message

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Is there any way to make it so `bquote(.(num)^4)` returns a single element, like is the case with the function `expression()`? Or is there any other function that I could use that would be the equivalent of `expression()`, but that can read variables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to make `vec[1]` as an expression.? You could use `plot(x=1, xlab = paste0(num, '^4'))`

Comment: Yeah, the end idea is to make a for loop that creates a vector of expression, but I couldn't figure out how to replace a variable name with its value before R logs it as an expression. I thought the solution was more complex, but turns out `as.expression()` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix characters and expressions in a vector. Note that your first chunk of code converted all of `vec` to an expression container. Observe

```
vec <- c("a","b","c","d")
class(vec)
# [1] "character"
vec[1] <- expression(num^4)
class(vec)
# [1] "expression"
vec
# expression(num^4, "b", "c", "d")
```

When you attempt to do the incompatible assignment, it gets coerced into an expression container object.

With expression containers as with lists, you need to use double brackets `[[ ]]` to set values. You can do

```
vec <- as.expression(c("a","b","c","d"))
num <- 3
vec[[1]] <- bquote(.(num)^4)
vec
# expression(3^4, "b", "c", "d")
```